# Create Table in visual force

Tags: visualforce

Good day

Please can you explain to me how to create a table with multiple rows in a visualforce page. First row describes an attribute and the other rows contain a textbox to enter the value of the attribute.

Below is the code that I tried out but its not giving me the layout that I require:

```
<apex:page sidebar="true" >
<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlock>
<apex:panelGrid columns="1" width="50%" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" >
  <apex:outputtext value="Network"/>
  <apex:inputtext />
  <apex:outputtext value="Size"/>
  <apex:inputtext />
  <apex:outputtext value="Assigned By"/>
  <apex:inputtext />
  <apex:outputtext value="Assign Date"/>
  <apex:inputtext /> 
  <apex:outputtext value="Percentage in Use"/>
  <apex:inputtext /> 
  <apex:commandbutton value="Save"/>
</apex:panelGrid>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**The layout that I am currently getting with the code snippet above is as follows:**

[image: Actual Table Layout]

**I would like to get the layout shown below:**

[image: Desired Table Layout]

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `apex:pageblocktable` for this.

```
<apex:pageBlock title="My Content">

    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!account.Contacts}" var="item">

        <apex:column value="{!item.name}"/> 

    </apex:pageBlockTable> 

</apex:pageBlock>
```

[Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_pageBlockTable.htm)

You can also use  `apex:repeat` to create HTML table and use your own custom styling.

Or can use apex:datatable to create a table.

[Reference and Difference between all of them](http://www.thephani.com/difference-between-pageblocktabe-datatable-repeat/)

Comment: Thanks @Tushar I looked at the suggested links. The thing is I want to capture data that is entered into the respective fields and not necessarily display data from any collections. Its a fill in form that I am currently working on

Comment: @user23 then use `apex:column` and `apex:inputfield` combination.

Comment: Hi @Tushar please can you assist me with an example of how I can go about the suggested proposal. Thank you